# Using php to fill a <select> on webpage. Looking for a faster load time

Tags: php, mysql, html, select

I added this :

```
<select>
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php include 'connect/config.php'; ?>
    <?php include 'connect/opendb.php'; ?>

    <?php
        $query = $db->query('SELECT type FROM card_type'); 
        $rows = $query->fetchAll(); 
        foreach($rows as $row) { 
        print '<option value="'.$row['type'].'">'.$row['type'].'</option>';
        }
    ?>
    <?php $db =null ?>
</select>
```

to my page and now it's takeing about 5 seconds longer to load the page.

Is there a more effecient way to fill a  option box from a database?

Comment: Do you really need to get this from a database? That the possible values change frequently? If not this should be in an array and included in a separate file if not directly put into your page (if it is only used in one page).

Comment: How many options are you fetching? It shouldn't take that long if it's just a few.

Comment: Right now it fetches about 30. Which I didn't think should take that long.

Comment: Also, the information is already in the database for other reasons. so I figured why not use it. It could be updated as often as every month or so.

Answer (score 2):

These are some issues in your code that affects performance:

1. **You should not call `print` for each row of your table**. That penalizes
   performance (if the server is not caching the output) as everytime
   you call `print` you will be sending bytes across the net which is a
   costly operation that is better be done **once for one big chunk of
   data** rather than **many times for small chunks of data** , that is
   the reason web servers will often cache all your PHP output prior to
   sending it to the browser.
2. You should **pass by reference the array value** when traversing the
   array with foreach, to avoid the copy of a variable in each
   iteration of the loop.
3. **Echo with commas, not periods**. If
   you use periods, PHP has to concatenate the string before it
   outputs. If you use commas, it just outputs them in order with no
   extra processing.
4. **You should use echo instead of `print()`**. As a language construct rather than a
   function, echo has a slight performance advantage over print().

So this is your code with points 2, 3 and 4 above corrected, thus assuming your web server is caching output:

```
<?php
      $query = $db->query('SELECT type FROM card_type'); 
      $rows = $query->fetchAll(); 
      foreach($rows as &$row) { 
          echo '<option value="', $row['type'] ,'">' ,$row['type'] , '</option>';
      }
?>
```

and this is your code with point 1 and 2 above corrected, thus assuming your web server is not caching the output:

```
<?php
      $query = $db->query('SELECT type FROM card_type'); 
      $rows = $query->fetchAll(); 
      $out = '';
      foreach($rows as &$row) { 
          $out .= '<option value="'.$row['type'].'">'.$row['type'].'</option>';
      }
      echo $out;
?>
```

Comment: [print is not actually a real function (it is a language construct).](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php)

I've no idea whether there's a performance difference or not. I'd never seen echo accepting multiple parameters though - have always used concatenate or just exited php and re-entered. `?>SOME HTML HERE<?php`

Don't all servers cache output? Surely they aren't sending tiny fragments of code for each echo.

Comment: This seems to go at about the same speed as what I've got now.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you're putting the entire database table into a php array. If your table is large, this may cause the delay in response.

Try this instead, for the part where you fill the `<select>`:

```
<?php
    $query = $db->query('SELECT type FROM card_type'); 
    while($row = $query->fetch_array()) { 
        print '<option value="'.$row['type'].'">'.$row['type'].'</option>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Tried it and for some reason it returns a completely black screen. No errors or anything just a black screen.

Comment: A black screen sounds like a fatal error: perhaps `fetch_array` is not available. I don't know which kind of database you are using. You could also try with `->fetch_assoc()` or `->fetch_row()` (and in that case change the array key from `'type'` to `0`). If none of this is working, I'd be so bold to believe the error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
<select>
  <option value=""></option>  
        <?php 
    include 'connect/config.php';
    include 'connect/opendb.php';
    $query = $db->query('SELECT type FROM card_type'); 
    $rows = $query->fetchAll(); 
    $select_option = '';
    foreach($rows as $row) { 
      $select_option .= '<option value="'.$row['type'].'">'.$row['type'].'</option>';
    }
    echo $select_option;
    unset($db);
    ?>
</select>
```